# Deriving the probability of a dart landing in an annulus

Tags: probability

In the book Probability and Statistics by Spiegel et al 2nd edition on page 62 they give the pdf of a dart striking between r and r+dr as:

$P(r \leq R \leq r + dr) = c[1 - (\frac{r}{a})^2]dr$

R is the distance from the center of the target
c is a constant (to normalise the probabiilty)
a is the radius of the target

I really can't see how they derived this?

Surely the area of an annulus is?

$2 \pi r dr$

So the cdf should be:

$\frac{2 \pi r dr}{\pi a^2}$

$\frac{2 r^2 dr}{a^2}$

Does the df mean you can treat is like an integral so that when you differentiate to get the pdf:

$\frac{2r^2}{a^2}$

That would be twice the complement of the expression given in the brackets?
However the full expression does include the dr term.

Can someone please explain how the expression given was derived?

Comment: Note:  The total area is $\pi a^2$, not $\pi r^2$ since $a$, not $r$,  is the radius of the target.

Answer (score 2):

What Spiegel et al. say is:

"A person playing darts finds that the probability of the dart striking between $\ r\ $ and $\ r + dr\ $ is
$$ P(r \leq R \leq r + dr) = c[1 - (\frac{r}{a})^2]dr \ ."$$
That is, they are *not* assuming that the point where the dart strikes the board is *uniformly distributed* over the board, which is what you appear to be assuming in your attempted derivation.

According to the distribution given by Spiegel et al., the dart is *more likely* to land in an area of some given size near the *centre* of the board than it is to land in an area of the same size further away from the centre.   If the dart thrower is aiming for the bullseye, and has at least some modicum of skill at darts, it would make more sense for the distribution to have this property than it would for it to be uniform.